# Open source (under the MIT licence) library for loading and saving image files?

Tags: graphics, open-source, licensing

I am writing an imaging library (using the MIT licence) and would like to hook it up to a library that supports loading and saving of images in various file formats (bmp, png, jpg etc)
I am aware of FreeImage, but it appears to use a GPL licence. Is there anything out there similar to FreeImage that uses MIT rather than GPL ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just so you know, there's also [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/features.php) and it is under the LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the PIL ([python image library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)).  It should do what you want and it looks like an MIT license (it has a free permissive one) .

Comment: not using python unfortunately